# Angular 6 Dynamic Forms issue

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-forms

I'm trying to master dynamic forms following the official documentation but with my own case.

I have api that I'm trying to fetch data from https://demo7782009.mockable.io/form and print it out in corresponding form fields.
Each field has own validation requirements.

But getting an error

> Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
>
> ```
>    Example:
>
>
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
> ```

I've tried to make a [plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/IXZvWuagww1QqewibcxZ?p=preview&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next&preview) with my app, but it doesn't bootstrap

So there is my code (sorry for that)

**App.component.ts**

```
import { FetchFormService } from './fetch-form.service';
import { QuestionControlService } from './question-control.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionBase } from './Models/question-base';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  questions: QuestionBase<any>[];
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private qcs: QuestionControlService,
    private ffs: FetchFormService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ffs.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.questions = data.data;
      let formQuestions: [QuestionBase<any>];
      this.questions.forEach(e => {
        formQuestions.push(new QuestionBase(e));
      });
      this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(formQuestions);
    });
  }

}
```

**App.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
    <app-question-item [question]="question" [index]='i' [form]="form"></app-question-item>
  </div>

  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**QuestionBase model**

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  value: T;
  values?: string[];
  label: string;
  type: string;

  constructor(options: {
    value: T,
    values?: string[],
    label: string,
    type: string
  }) {
    this.value = options.value;
    this.label = options.label;
    this.type = options.type;
    this.values = options.values;
  }
}
```

**Question-item.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { QuestionBase } from '../Models/question-base';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-question-item',
  templateUrl: './question-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question-item.component.css']
})
export class QuestionItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() question: QuestionBase<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  @Input() index;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Question-item.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label>
    {{ question.label }}

    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="question.type">
      <input [formControlName]="'field' + index" *ngSwitchCase="'string' || 'integer' || 'double'" type="text">

      <textarea [formControlName]="'field' + index" *ngSwitchCase="'text'" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

      <ul *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
        <li *ngFor="let item of question.values; let subindex = index">
          <input [formControlName]="'field' + index + subindex" type="text">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-container>

  </label>
</div>
```

**Fetch-form.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Form {
  data: {
    type: string,
    label: string,
    value: string,
    values?: string[]
  }[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchFormService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get<Form>('https://demo7782009.mockable.io/form');
  }
}
```

**Question-control.service.ts**

```
import { QuestionBase } from './Models/question-base';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QuestionControlService {
  constructor() { }

  toFormGroup(questsions: QuestionBase<any>[]) {
    let group: any = {};

    questsions.forEach((e, i) => {
      if (e.type === 'string' || e.type === 'text' || e.type === 'list') {
        group[i] = new FormControl(e.value, Validators.required);
      } else if (e.type === 'integer') {
        group[i] = new FormControl(e.value, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\d+/)]);
      } else if (e.type === 'double') {
        group[i] = new FormControl(e.value, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/\d+\.\d+/)]);
      } else {}
    });

    return new FormGroup(group);
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { QuestionItemComponent } from './question-item/question-item.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuestionItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

### Continuation of this questions is here

[Angular 6 Dynamic Forms issue [part 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762013/angular-6-dynamic-forms-issue-part-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared you form

```
form: FormGroup;
```

But forgot to instanciate it. You did this

```
this.form = this.qcs.toFormGroup(...);
```

But you are waiting for your HTTP call to complete, meaning that it's undefined until the call is done.

Consider conditioning your HTML :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
```

By the way, for sandboxes, consider using http://stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you. That solved one problem but I've got another one then. `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'formQuestions.push')` although it shouldn't be that since it's placed in subscription after assigning received data

Comment: same issue : you declare it `let formQuestions: [QuestionBase<any>]`, but don't instantiate it `let formQuestions: [QuestionBase<any>] = [];`

Comment: So simple mistakes I made... Thought that it's enough to declare type... Now it prints out one field with error `Cannot find control with name: 'field0'` (I'm generating them in HTML template since I don't have any fields name due to different amount of fields each time

Comment: Well you shouldn't. That's a rather advanced issue compared to the ones you resolved, I suggest you make a new question for it so that it doesn't pollute this one.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your help. Stackblitz looks more advanced in comparison to plunker I'll try to place my code there instead.

Comment: That is a continuation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762013/angular-6-dynamic-forms-issue-part-2

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is quite common, it has nothing to do with dynamic forms. When you init your component, the html template is loaded. Before that your ngOnInit is fired but it is still waiting for the response from your backend. Therefor your "form" variable is undefined. Because your template is being loaded with `[formGroup]="undefined"` you get that error.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
```

The ngIf fixes the problem because it will make sure your form template isn't trying to load before you are sure your formgroup is created.

Comment: When your answer is the same as one on the page, and it brings nothing more, consider upvoting the said answer instead of making a duplicate. This would help future users by reducing the number of answers, and showing the most upvoted ones.