# Angular 6 Dynamic Forms issue [part 2]

Tags: angular, typescript, dynamic-forms

Following recommendations from [Angular 6 Dynamic Forms issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760979/angular-6-dynamic-forms-issue) I've made my app to print one field out, but only one empty and with an error

> ERROR
>   Error: Cannot find control with name: 'field0'

I've placed my code here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzu1ab

I'm generating field names by indices, since the data that I fetch contains no name fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you create your form control names dynamically, but you don't really bind them to your questions.

Instead of chosing an arbitrary name like `field + i`, you should instead bind on a specific value.

In this [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7kgxhs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion-item%2Fquestion-item.component.html), I binded the form control names to the label, and as you can see, it works like a charm.

```html
<input [formControlName]="question.label"
```

```js
questsions.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (e.type === 'string' || e.type === 'text' || e.type === 'list') {
    group[e.label] = new FormControl(e.value, Validators.required);
```

Comment: Although it works, I suggest you edit your API to return a new key, such as `inputName`, because labels contain spaces, and I'm not a fan of that

Comment: What if I cannot do anything for API? (this one is just a part of one test case for job appliance). Also by some reason `ngSwitch` works doesn't consider `integer`, `double`. And `list` cannot be printed out in that case, cause we have an array under one label. What could you advise me?

Comment: Well keep the label then, it's a string after all, there's no reason it shouldn't work, I'm not just a fan of it. About the other issues, the `switch` behaves like a real switch : one value per case. About your list, you should use a select instead of lists. [**This stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppexu4?file=src/app/question-item/question-item.component.html) shows you how it will render with that being applied (sorry, I removed the textarea to be faster)

Comment: @Sergey I would also advise you to treat string & text the same way, and integer & double the same way : in Javascript, they have no differences, they're just `string` and `number`.

Comment: Thank you but this is just to follow requirements to the test. They have different Validators and fields as well as list of inputs should be :) I'll try to use `FormArray` for that. Hope it will help

Comment: Good luck with your project and job application !